# Autocomplete not working when array is filled from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I used to use this kind of code before like 1 year ago and it worked.
Now I got a problem with the php code **when I fill my array with elements from the database** I can't do the autocomplete, but when I comment the part where I get the code form the database and  uncomment //$elements = array("25qt", "45tr", "az12"); than the autocomplete works.
It looks like the array is filled correctly from the database cause when I open the php file alone and  do a var_dump($elements); i get the content of the array accordingly. Any idea why its not working when i fill the array from the db but it works if I use an array like $elements = array("25qt", "45tr", "az12");.

HTML code:

```
<input id="tegjithepjeset" type="text" class="form-control">
```

jQuery code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                      $("#tegjithepjeset").autocomplete({
                      source:'allParts.php',
                      minLength:1

                      });
                    });
    </script>
```

Php code:

```
<?php
 // An empty array:
$data = array();

// Create connection
include 'dbinfo.php';
$con=@mysqli_connect("$host","$user","$password","$db");


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$queryString = "SELECT code FROM  ".$table;
$query =mysqli_query($con,$queryString);

$elements = array();

while($rowDB=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $elements[]="".$rowDB[0];

}
//var_dump($elements);

//$elements = array("25qt", "45tr", "az12");

//Loop through the array to find matches:
  foreach ($elements as $elm) {

    // Add matches to the $data array:
    if (stripos($elm, $_GET['term']) !== false) $data[] = $elm;//here we fill our empty array with values

  } // End of FOREACH.



// Return the data:
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: There are a lot of autocomplete libraries. Which one are you using?

Comment: can you show the output of var_dump($elements);

Comment: try replacing $elements[]="".$rowDB[0]; with $elements[]=$rowDB[0];

Comment: @RavinderReddy this is what the var dump was giving to me before fixing with your suggestion :
array(20) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(5) "14LU4" [4]=> string(5) "25QT6" [5]=> string(5) "14LU4" [6]=> string(5) "kj345" [7]=> string(5) "kdfer" [8]=> string(5) "25QT7" [9]=> string(5) "14LU5" [10]=> string(5) "kj346" [11]=> string(5) "14LU5" [12]=> string(5) "kj346" [13]=> string(5) "kdfer" [14]=> string(5) "25QT8" [15]=> string(5) "14LU6" [16]=> string(0) "" [17]=> string(5) "14LU2" [18]=> string(5) "25QT5" [19]=> string(5) "14LU3" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the $elements array code as shown below.

```
$elements = array();
while($rowDB=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   // $elements[]="".$rowDB[0];
    $elements[]=$rowDB[0];
}
```

Comment: Its works thx , btw I  am pretty sure  I did what you suggested before asking here but I might have messed something else.

Comment: @AlbanKaperi I'm glad I helped. Accept is as correct answer, so that other can use this code.